# Android: Google Drive onActivityResult() getting resultCode 0 (RESULT_CANCELED)

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I've been scouring the Google documentation and sample code and Stack Overflow for a solution to this, and while I've seen a number of people running into the same symptoms I haven't found anything that helps in my particular case.

Basically I'm trying to do an auth workflow for the Google Drive REST API, and while I get as far as the Google account selection page, when it returns to my calling activity, I'm always seeing a result of RESULT_CANCELED (i.e., 0) instead of RESULT_OK (i.e., -1), no matter what account is selected.

I've checked to make sure that the credentials are set up correctly on the Google developer console — and they were working previously with authentication via the now-defunct CloudRail library. (As far as I can tell, now with Google Sign-In you *don't* provide any client id, etc.: that's all handled on Google's end when it matches your package name.)

Here is my call for authentication:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
            .build();
    mSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, signInOptions);
```

And here is the activity's `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {
                /*** NEVER GET HERE ***/
                handleSignInResult(this, resultData);
            }
            else {
                /*** ALWAYS GET HERE ***/
                Log.e(TAG, String.format("Unable to complete Google sign-in (resultCode: %d)", resultCode));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
}
```

I'm assuming that this is a case of me doing something obviously dumb and wrong — and was hoping that just typing out the question would help me figure out what it is, but that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: can you share the error code you recieved

Comment: Always getting `resultCode == 0` (`Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`) instead of the expected -1 (`Activity.RESULT_OK`).

Answer (score 8):

As I expected, it was something relatively simple that I was doing wrong. So for anyone having the same issue and stepping over my body while searching for a solution, here's what I found:

While I *did* have the credentials in the Google developer console set up correctly, with my package name and SHA1 generated, as directed by the documentation, from mykeystore.keystore, what I missed was that Android Studio *doesn't sign debug builds with mykeystore.keystore by default*. Instead it uses its own provided debug.keystore.

So the thing to do is to create a new OAuth client ID with your package name and the SHA1 from Android Studio's debug.keystore instead of one's own. (You can either hunt down debug.keystore on your system, or run the Gradle "signingReport" task and get it from there.)

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

First of all most probably it all happens because you add the credential.json from the Google Drive API console.
I suggest you to create a project in Firebase console and add its google.json for validation of authentication.

and in your onActivityResult you can check the error code using following code:

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (callbackManager != null) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            handleSignInResult(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
             System.out.println("errorCode = " + e.getStatusCode());// Print this error code on your console 
        }
    }

}
```

if the error code is 12500 then your problem with keys validation and hence you need to create a firebase project and add your machine SHA1 code and then use its google.json file in your app root folder.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'm puzzled, though. This is the first time I've read anything about Firebase with regard to authenticating to use Google Drive — nowhere on Google's own pages, in its Github samples, etc. does it mention Firebase. I have currently not added any credential.json to the project (i.e., I haven't downloaded anything from the developer console). `e.getStatusCode()` returns 10.

Comment: Error code 10 is DEVELOPER_ERROR:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#DEVELOPER_ERROR

This almost certainly means you have not properly registered your SHA1 and Package Name in the Google API console:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

If you are 100% sure that you have done this correctly, make sure that your GoogleSignInOptions are correct. In particular, make sure the web client ID (if you're using it) belongs to the same project where you registered your package name and SHA1.

Comment: I will suggest you to create a new project in Firebase and it will guide you to its step by step process. Then it will provide a google.json file which you need to download and include in your project app root folder.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I'd run into the ApiException error earlier when I was doing things in a more roundabout way previously, but I thought I had thoroughly checked to make sure that the credentials were set up correctly. I've posted a more detailed answer here explaining why they were, in fact, not. Thanks again.